# How to convert multi dotted string to float value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file which contain a  numeric string with multiple dots like `'1.2.3'`. I would like to convert this number to float or int like `'1.2.3'` so that later on this number can be compared with other numbers. I use python 3.5 under linux. To explain the problem, consider this simple example:-

```
$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> _str = '1.2.3'
>>> float(_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.2.3'
>>> _str = '1.2'
>>> float(_str)
1.2
```

It is very clear that the python does not consider the numbers containing multiple dot as float. I have done lot of search but no one seems to have similar problem.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Do you really want a float or a list of ints so you can compare two lists of ints in order from first to last element?

Comment: I want float not a list of numbers.

Comment: Well you can't 1.2.3 is not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a class which I have called WrongFloat because what you are asking for is not a float

```
from itertools import izip_longest

class WrongFloat:
    def __init__(self, val):
        if isinstance(val, WrongFloat):
            self.parts = val.parts[:]
        elif isinstance(val, str):
            self.parts=[int(v) for v in val.split('.')]
        elif isinstance(val, float):
            self.parts=str(val).split('.')
        elif isinstance(val, int):
            self.parts=[val]

    def __str__(self):
        return ".".join([str(v) for v in self.parts])


    def __lt__(self, val):
        o = WrongFloat(val)
        parts = list(izip_longest(self.parts, o.parts, fillvalue=0))
        for p in parts:
            if p[0] > p[1]:
                return False

        if parts[-1][0] == parts[-1][1]:
            return False
        return True

    def __le__(self, val):
        o = WrongFloat(val)
        parts = list(izip_longest(self.parts, o.parts, fillvalue=0))
        for p in parts:
            if p[0] > p[1]:
                return False
        return True        

    def __eq__(self, val):
        o = WrongFloat(val)
        first, second = tuple(zip(*list(izip_longest(self.parts, o.parts, fillvalue=0))))
        return first == second

    def __ne__(self, val):
        o = WrongFloat(val)
        first, second = tuple(zip(*list(izip_longest(self.parts, o.parts, fillvalue=0))))
        return first != second

    def __gt__(self, val):
        o = WrongFloat(val)
        parts = list(izip_longest(self.parts, o.parts, fillvalue=0))
        for p in parts:
            if p[0] < p[1]:
                return False

        if parts[-1][0] == parts[-1][1]:
            return False
        return True

    def __ge__(self, val):
        o = WrongFloat(val)
        parts = list(izip_longest(self.parts, o.parts, fillvalue=0))
        for p in parts:
            if p[0] < p[1]:
                return False
        return True
```

The **init** will create an instance from string, float, int or another WrongFloat

So this is possible for construction

```
a = WrongFloat("1.2.3")
print a

b = WrongFloat(1.2)
print b

c = WrongFloat(1)
print c

d = WrongFloat(a)
print d

try:
    e = WrongFloat("d.r.f")
except ValueError:
    print "ValueError"
```

Added the methods **gt**, **ge**, **le**, **lt**, **eq** and **ne** so you can compare two values

```
print a < "1.2.4"
print a < "1.2.3"
print a < "1.2.2"
print a < "1.2.3.1"
print a < "1.2.3.0"
print a < "1.2.2.9"

print a <= "1.2.4"
print a <= "1.2.3"
print a <= "1.2.2"
print a <= "1.2.3.1"
print a <= "1.2.3.0"
print a <= "1.2.2.9"

print a == "1.2.4"
print a == "1.2.3"
print a == "1.2.2"

print a != "1.2.4"
print a != "1.2.3"
print a != "1.2.2"

print a <= "1.2.2"
print a <= "1.2.3"
print a <= "1.2.4"

print a < "1.2.2"
print a < "1.2.3"
print a < "1.2.4"
```

You could also have **add** and **sub** methods for addition and subtraction, I don't think multiplication and division are sensible for this made up float type  with multiple dots